# Centering histogram bins and setting percentage range in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I'm doing data-analysis in Matlab and I'm plotting the frequencies of discrete values (1-15) into a histogram on Matlab. I would like to center the bins so that the center of 1st bin is on value 1, center of the 2nd bin is on value 2, etc.

Also I would like to get percentage range for the Y-axis. Any quick ideas how to do this? Here is a picture highlighting my question:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) (which needs bin **centers** and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) (which needs bin **edges**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html#btsgtr0-1) with your expected centers. Then use `bar` and `xlabel` to display the histogram with the y axis the way you want:

```
dat = randi(15,100,1);
centers = 1:15;
counts = hist(dat,centers);
pcts = 100 * counts / sum(counts);
bar(centers,counts)
ylabel('%')
```