# create a histogram from a cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, histogram

I've done the nearest neighbour program in matlab for 547 points and I result with a cell array of size <547x1 cell> here are the data:

Cell array =

```
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x8 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x8 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x8 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x9 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x9 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x9 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x7 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x8 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x8 double]
[1x6 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x5 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x8 double]
[1x3 double]
```

the data describes for each particle how many neighbours I have,what I wish to do is represent this data in histogram so that one can visualize easily how many time I have 6 neihbours how many times 4 ,5 ,7 ,8...sure it's hard for me to read between the lines and see how many 6 or X number do I have if anyone can help to suggest a way to represent and quantify these data in a histogram I'd be thankful

**EDIT**: Answer below for histogram generation with percentages.

[image]

I plotted the histogram using:

```
          [nelements,centers]=hist(cellfun(@numel,S));
          numNeighbors = cellfun(@numel,S);
          [nelements,centers]=hist(numNeighbors,unique(numNeighbors))
          pcts = 100 * nelements / sum(nelements)
          figure
          bar(centers,pcts)
```

displaying on the y axis the percentage of each xvalue occurance,now is it possible to show the percentages numbers on the histogram as I added in the image above so one can easily visualize the numbers ???

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question to show a small representative part of the cell array rather than the whole thing.

Comment: Now that the initial question is answered, you can start a new question for the `text`/`annotation` request.  Otherwise you won't get much attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your cell array is `C`, then try `hist(cellfun(@numel,C))`.  For better display, maybe:

```
numNeighbors = cellfun(@numel,C);
hist(numNeighbors,unique(numNeighbors))
```

Comment: powerful and great answer thank you,do you have an idea about getting the percentage display on the y axis for each values ???

Comment: @SarahAl-Jawhari - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448650/centering-histogram-bins-and-setting-percentage-range-in-matlab/19456075#19456075.