# how to display percentage label for each value on histogram in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

Using [the answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19530663/2778484), I plotted the histogram for a cell array using:

```
   [nelements,centers]=hist(cellfun(@numel,S));
      numNeighbors = cellfun(@numel,S);
      [nelements,centers]=hist(numNeighbors,unique(numNeighbors))
      pcts = 100 * nelements / sum(nelements)
      figure
      bar(centers,pcts)
```

[image]

Displaying on the y axis the percentage of each xvalue occurrence, is it possible to show the percentages numbers on the histogram as I added in the image above so one can easily visualize the numbers?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-to-graphs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `text` function is IMHO the friendliest of the annotation objects because it accepts graph coordinates rather than normalized figure coordinates.

```
K = numel(centers);
for k = 1:K
    text(centers(k),pcts(k),[num2str(pcts(k)) '%'],'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','bottom')
end
```

This will put the percentage value at the top of each bar. Look at the help page for `text` for further enhancements, like controlling the position, color, font, etc. of the placed text.

Comment: true (Y),thank you and the trivial way to do it by hand with insert textbox but this is more powerful thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

[Histogram Percentage](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59361-histogram-percentage)

[image]